# create GeoJSON for loop used?

Tags: geojson

#### create JSON file

Here I want to use the min and max of x and y, then I have 4 points for the polygon. But how to loop through precinct?

And I cannot get the JSON working.

```
z.sub <- subset(z, (z$Violation.Precinct %in% police.precincts))

z.long.min <- NULL
z.long.max <- NULL
z.lat.min <- NULL
z.lat.max <- NULL

### find coordinates for each precinct 
for(i in 1:length(police.precincts)){
  z.long.min[i] <- min(hulls[hulls$Violation.Precinct == police.precincts[i],]$x)
  z.long.max[i] <- max(hulls[hulls$Violation.Precinct == police.precincts[i],]$x)
  z.lat.min[i] <- min(hulls[hulls$Violation.Precinct == police.precincts[i],]$y)
  z.lat.max[i] <- max(hulls[hulls$Violation.Precinct == police.precincts[i],]$y) 
}

s <- {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [z.long.min[1], z.lat.min[1]], [z.long.min[1], z.lat.max[1]], [z.long.max[1], z.lat.min[1]], [z.long.max[1], z.lat.max[1]], [z.long.min[1], z.long.max[1]]
        ]
      ]
  },
  "properties": {
    "precinct": 1
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please specify what language this is